# Verlet collision with impulse preservation

Tags: physics

I came across [this](http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/nov/29/verlet-collision-with-impulse-preservation/) article, recently, that presented a technique for impulse preservation with position-based verlet integration. What was interesting was that the integration steps are seemingly done differently from typical position-based verlet schemes, as well as the ordering of the integration step and collision resolutions.

---

Specifically, the typical verlet position integrator is:

```
newPosition = 2 * position - oldPosition + acceleration * timeStepSquared
oldPosition = position
position = newPosition
DoConstraints()
```

Where the article has:

```
position += acceleration * timeStepSquared
DoConstraints()
newPosition = position * 2 - oldPosition
oldPosition = position
position = newPosition
```

Which ignoring constraints for a moment works out to be:

```
newPosition = 2*position - oldPosition + 2*acceleration*timeStepSquared
oldPosition = position + acceleration*timeStepSquared
position = newPosition
```

Which is different in a term of `acceleration * timeStepSquared`.  I haven't quite convinced myself that those terms cancel out through the iteration, as the prior `acceleration * timeStepSquared` term may not be the same as the current one.

---

Could someone explain the reasoning for this, and if indeed it makes sense?

Comment: the link seems to be broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start understanding what is actually happening in that code is to.. reverse engineer it. (see this source file http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/nov/29/verlet-collision-with-impulse-preservation/final2.js).

The main loop simply call this function

```
 var step = function(){
        var steps = 2;
        var delta = 1/steps;
        for(var i=0; i<steps; i++){
            gravity();
            accelerate(delta);
            collide(false);
            border_collide();
            inertia(delta);
            collide(true);
            border_collide_preserve_impulse();
        }
        draw();
    }
```

Without actually going into any of the *collision handling logic*, let's see what happens mathematically in that code, assuming we have a single body to simulate. This way we can check, as you pointed out, if the integrator is a position-Verlet or not, and what it actually does.

Let `x` be the position vector at the future time instance and `px` the position vector at the previous time instance. Further let's assume only 1 integration step is performed. This is what happens to `x` and `px` as a consequence of calling the `step()` function:

1. `x += a * Dt*Dt`
2. `alter(x,px)` as a result of the collision handling code (may be omitted!)
3. `xx = 2*x - px`. If we omit collisions, `xx = 2*x + 2*a*Dt^2 - px`
4. `px = x`
5. `x = xx`
6. `alter(x,px)` as a result of the collision handling code

We can indeed omit steps 2 and 6. If we do this, the integrator does the following

1. x = px
2. repeat:

   a. `x = x + a*Dt^2`
   b.  `xx = 2*x - px = px + 2*a*Dt^2`
   c. `px = x`
   d. `x = xx`

The original Verlet integrator requires estimating the state at three consecutive instances, `x[n+1], x[n]` and `x[n-1]` knowing that

- `x[n+1] = x[n] + v[n]*Dt + 1/2a[n]*Dt`
- `v[n] = (x[n+1] - x[n-1])/(2*Dt)`

hence `x[n+1] = 2*x[n] - x[n-1] + a[n]*Dt^2`, `x[n-1] = x[n]`, `x[n] = x[n+1]`.

The code inside the `step()` procedure is doing `x[n+1] = 2*(x[n] + a[n]*Dt^2) - x[n-1]`, `x[n-1] = x[n]`, `x[n] = x[n+1]`.

**Conclusion:** the integration is performed through position-Verlet, *but* there is an error since the acceleration at instance `[n]` is twice what the Physics world reports. Nevertheless, the author of that code only considered gravity, which, as far as we are concerned, is simply double the input supplied in the `accelerate` method.

Comment: Hmm you have basically confirmed the same equation I gave in my question that I worked out already from his code which showed an error of 'acceleration * timeStepSquared'.  But your last sentence is an important point as if this is an error maybe that's why he didn't notice in this case.  Still I am not sure there isn't some reasoning behind it given the different then usual order he approaches constraints.  I guess best way to be sure is to contact him then.

Comment: So the only difference is that you apply double the total acceleration. Which is actually incorrect from many points of view, but in this case it means you have double the gravity of the world you're simulating the bodies in.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was something sneaky going on regards some sort of cascading of prior acceleration terms and the way around he did his constraint resolution.  But the more I look at and similar stuff I think it's as you say a simple mistake and nothing more clever under the hood.

Comment: The trick the author concocted was to first apply the acceleration-induced translation, then to satisfy the constraints (coming from collision detection in their case). Separating the `accelerate()` and `inertia()` functions like that is indeed incorrect. The plausibility, however, is not affected. I must think a bit deeper what exactly this integrator is most similar to. It is definitely not a pure positon-Verlet, more of a modified semi-implicit Euler. Food for thought.

Comment: I was looking at the derivation of the symplectic Euler and position verlet when I wrote the question wondering if there was some sort of additional delayed step approximation he had done that I was missing given the terrible state of my maths these days.  Coupled with the fact I have been trying to get the right mental model for viewing how the typical projective constraint satisfaction/relaxation ties into the integration step given all the approximations and assumptions this kind of stuff makes - which made his modification more intriguing.  But that's probably another question...